# Why is a datetime string format not reversible?

Tags: python, datetime

I expected `datetime.strftime` and `datetime.strptime` calls to be reversible. Such that calling

```py
datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime(fmt), fmt))
```

Would give the closest reconstruction of `now()` (given the information preserved by the format).

However, this is not the case when formatting a date to a string with a `YYYY-Week#` format:

```py
>>> yyyy_u = datetime.datetime(1992, 5, 17).strftime('%Y-%U')
>>> print(yyyy_u)
'1992-20'
```

Formatting the string back to a date does not give the expected response:

```py
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(yyyy_u, '%Y-%U')
datetime.datetime(1992, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

I would have expected the response to be the first day of week 20 in 1992 (17 May 1992).

Is this a failure of the `%U` format option or more generally are `datetime.strftime` and `datetime.strptime` calls not meant to be reversible?

Comment: Formatting a point in time as a string may easily reduce the resolution, which is information that is lost irrevocably. Other problems like DST or leap seconds further complicate this in cornercases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) regarding `strptime()` behaviour:

> 6. When used with the strptime() method, %U and %W are only used in calculations when the day of the week and the year are specified.

Day of the week must be specified along with Week number and Year.
`(%Y-%U-%w)`

`datetime.datetime.strptime('1992-20-0', '%Y-%U-%w')` gives the first day of week 20 for 1992 year.